# Leftpad Zeros with length check in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

```
<LineProcessInfo>
  <LineRefTextField1>JPY</LineRefTextField1>
  <LineRefTextField2>[MW09449_ _048]</LineRefTextField2>
  <LineRefTextField3>[00_L]</LineRefTextField3>
  <LineRefTextField4></LineRefTextField4>
  <LineRefTextField5>AS LAMBSWOOL VNECK</LineRefTextField5>
  <LineRefTextField6>Jet Black Heath</LineRefTextField6>
  <LineRefTextField7></LineRefTextField7>
  <LineRefTextField8>WH01</LineRefTextField8>
  <LineRefTextField9></LineRefTextField9>
  <LineRefTextField10></LineRefTextField10>
  <LineRefNumberField1></LineRefNumberField1>
  <LineRefNumberField2></LineRefNumberField2>
  <LineRefNumberField3>22</LineRefNumberField3>
  <LineRefNumberField4></LineRefNumberField4>
  <LineRefNumberField5></LineRefNumberField5>
</LineProcessInfo>
```

value : if (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefNumberField3 != null) (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefNumberField3) else ""

For LineRefNumberField3 length should be 5 and if it is less 5 then pad zeros to the left, i need to get 00022, Please suggest how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use leftPad as documented in https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-strings-functions-leftpad

Sample code below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

import * from dw::core::Strings

var payload = read("<LineProcessInfo><LineRefTextField1>JPY</LineRefTextField1>
          <LineRefTextField2>[MW09449_ _048]</LineRefTextField2>
          <LineRefTextField3>[00_L]</LineRefTextField3>
          <LineRefTextField4></LineRefTextField4>
          <LineRefTextField5>AS LAMBSWOOL VNECK</LineRefTextField5>
          <LineRefTextField6>Jet Black Heath</LineRefTextField6>
          <LineRefTextField7></LineRefTextField7>
          <LineRefTextField8>WH01</LineRefTextField8>
          <LineRefTextField9></LineRefTextField9>
          <LineRefTextField10></LineRefTextField10>
          <LineRefNumberField1></LineRefNumberField1>
          <LineRefNumberField2></LineRefNumberField2>
          <LineRefNumberField3>22</LineRefNumberField3>
          <LineRefNumberField4></LineRefNumberField4>
          <LineRefNumberField5></LineRefNumberField5>
        </LineProcessInfo>", "application/xml")
---

{
    LineRefNumberField3: leftPad(payload.LineProcessInfo.LineRefNumberField3, 5, "0") default ""
}
```

**Edit:**
If using Mule Runtime v4.1.x

```
(payload.LineProcessInfo.LineRefNumberField3 as Number default "") as String {format : "00000"}
```

Comment: import * from dw::core::Strings this is not working for Mule runtime 4.1.5. Please tell me what needs to be added

Comment: import * from dw::core::Strings this is not working for Mule runtime 4.1.5. it works for 4.2.1 but i cannot use 4.2.1  as per client requirement. Please suggest.